# Можно ли собрать rpm пакет используя makefile

Tags: kotlin, devops, package, centos7, rpm

Уже долго сижу и не могу ничего найти, можно ли собрать rpm пакет командой make через makefile? Хочу попробовать собрать именно через makefile.

Comment: По минимуму, напишите в нем 2 строки `all:` и `тут табуляция echo make rpm...` на новой строке (естественно, в следующих строках шелловские команды для сборки пакета) и при запуске make такой makefile всегда будет работать

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли мне, не через makefile я смог собрать, но вот с makefile возникла проблема. Вот только где стоит расположить makefile, в папке с исходниками и оттуда запускать его?

Comment: Неожиданный вопрос. Я бы положил его в то место, откуда обычно выполняю эту работу (вообще-то, rpm-ы я не собираю -)). В любом сучае, можно вызвать вот так `make -f my-makefile.mk`, задав путь к файлу. А также, советую почитать документацию для программирования в  [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) (наверное, при желании можно и на русском найти)